# How to change values across 1 row based on values in a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I have a lot of columns in 1 dataframe that identify different timepoints of the same variable. Basically, within my data, if there's no response at timepoint X-1, there will be no response at time point X or beyond (after an NA appears in a row, it will continue). I currently have a column that shows which row the last response came from and what that response is. The dataframe currently looks like this:

```
  id X1 X2 X3 X4 X_final X_final_location
1  1  5  5  6 NA       6               X3
2  2  4 NA NA NA       4               X1
3  3  7  1  3  5       5               X4
4  4  8  2  4  2       2               X4
5  5  1  5 NA NA       5               X2
6  6  5  7  7  7       7               X4
```

My goal is to be able to conduct a regression using the last response of each row as the outcome variable. However, I don't want it to repeat twice in the "X_final" column and also in the column that the response actually comes from. Therefore, I am hoping to find a way to put a "." in for the cell where that value originally came from so it looks like this:

```
  id X1   X2 X3 X4 X_final X_final_location
1  1  5    5  6 NA       6               X3
2  2  . <NA> NA NA       4               X1
3  3  7    1  3  5       5               X4
4  4  8    2  4  2       2               X4
5  5  1    . NA NA       5               X2
6  6  5    7  7  7       7               X4
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, putting a "." in place of a number will convert all the data in that column to character instead of numeric. Why not NA instead?

Comment: I see, I didn't think of that but I think NA would work too! Any way to just be able to identify that number and get rid of it so it's not part of the dataframe anymore. Do you have a suggestion on it ouputting NA?

Comment: Why do the 1,3,4,6 rows not need to be replaced, while only the 2, 5 rows need? What's the logic?

Comment: You're right @Darren Tsai, the last column for all rows should be replaced, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method, since you already have the locations in `$X_final_location`. As mentioned in the question comments, `NA` values would be preferred if the goal would be regression analysis to preserve numeric values.

```
data_orig <- data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    X1 = c(5, 4, 7, 8, 1, 5),
    X2 = c(5, NA, 1, 2, 5, 7),
    X3 = c(6, NA, 3, 4, NA, 7),
    X4 = c(NA, NA, 5, 2, NA, 7),
    X_final = c(6, 4, 5, 2, 5, 7),
    X_final_location = c("X3", "X1", "X4", "X4", "X2", "X4")
)

data_new <- data_orig
for (i in seq_len(nrow(data_new))) {
    data_new[i, data_new$X_final_location[i]] <- NA
}

data_new

#   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X_final X_final_location
# 1  1  5  5 NA NA       6               X3
# 2  2 NA NA NA NA       4               X1
# 3  3  7  1  3 NA       5               X4
# 4  4  8  2  4 NA       2               X4
# 5  5  1 NA NA NA       5               X2
# 6  6  5  7  7 NA       7               X4
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this (NA instead of . to preserve data type):
`match` finds the first NA position, `replace` replaces the value in that position - 1 (previous) with NA.
`apply(data, 1,  \(x) ...)` applies that function for each row. Finally `t` transposes the result (since apply by default coerces the result to columns.

```r
data = data.frame(id = 1:6, X1 = c(5L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 5L), X2 = c(5L, 
NA, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L), X3 = c(6L, NA, 3L, 4L, NA, 7L), X4 = c(NA, 
NA, 5L, 2L, NA, 7L), X_final = c(6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L), X_final_location = c("X3", 
"X1", "X4", "X4", "X2", "X4"))

data[,2:5] <- t(apply(data[,2:5], 1 , function(x) replace(x, match(NA, x) - 1, NA)))

data
#>   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X_final X_final_location
#> 1  1  5  5 NA NA       6               X3
#> 2  2 NA NA NA NA       4               X1
#> 3  3  7  1  3  5       5               X4
#> 4  4  8  2  4  2       2               X4
#> 5  5  1 NA NA NA       5               X2
#> 6  6  5  7  7  7       7               X4
```

Another way using split (grouping by row):

```
split(data, row.names(data)) <- 
   lapply(split(data, row.names(data)), \(x) replace(x, x$X_final_location, "."))
```